# How can I use images in Plotly instead of just coloured dots?

Tags: plotly.js

I was trying the examples in the documentation and they are relatively easy. And it makes sense to use images or at least one image instead of those coloured dots. What I tried so far is this:

```
const x = Array.from({ length: 500, }, () => Math.random() * (6 - 3) + 3);
const y = Array.from({ length: 500, }, () => Math.random() * (6 - 3) + 3);

const data = [{
    x,
    y,
    type: 'image',
    mode: 'markers',
    source: icon,
    name: 'Some Image',
    showlegend: true
}];

Plotly.newPlot('chart', data);
```

Here I am trying to render images instead of dots, but all I get is an image in the entire graph. How can I make every individual dot be the actual image. And here I mean icons, to be more precise, I want to use a wheel icon - .

Answer (score 0):

All I had to add was this:

```
marker: {symbol: "hexagon2-dot"}
```